# Array of references for an array of React objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

To use ref for a react component we use something like:

```
  <MyReactObject ref = {instance => {this.child_MyReactObject = instance}}
                  ...
  />
```

I need to create an array of  MyReactObject  and I need to get references for each  MyReactObject  . Any idea on how can this be done?

thx

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's probably a better idea to create a separate `ref` inside every `MyReactObject` component instead of an array of refs in the parent.

Comment: Each   MyReactObject  has a state field called Total. Basically, I need to get all the Total fields and add them. I want to create a function called  getTotal()  in MyReactObject  that will be used to get that Total value. Using ref is possible to get to those functions.

Comment: Alright. Then it might be worth looking into the technique of [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so that you store the total of each `MyReactObject` in the parent instead and pass it down as a prop.

Comment: I tried that... but since I have been forced to use   componentWillReceiveProps  (react 15.*) then I got in a kind of long loop.

Comment: Maybe [this can give some inspiration](https://codesandbox.io/s/jly8mkop45).

Comment: I think I will try your approach.. and just pass the function to increase that total value. Thx

Comment: An error I got, given that my components are making IO ops, says something like: applying set state to a non loaded react component...

Comment: @Tholle I finally did something like you said, but placing the total as prop for MyReactObject. So, in my array I have something like  push(<MyReactObject total = {someValue} ... />) and now I can pick this value from the array of these objects. Thx